# Oracle Query Optimisation of a tricky delete query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization, sql-delete

We had a delete query built for a table(has 2 Billion rows already) in our Oracle DB. This query was executed as part of a PL/SQL Proc. Below is our current query that is still in testing.

```
DELETE from TABLE1 
    where ROWID IN (SELECT rid from (SELECT ROWID rid, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY C1_Varchar2,C2_Varchar2 ORDER BY C3_Date desc) as Rank 
                                from TABLE1 where C3_Date < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -20))
                where Rank <> 1);
```

This query is to delete all the records(from TABLE1) that are older than 20 months from current month except for the latest record formed by unique combination of C1 and C2 columns. An approx 12% of records will be deleted with this query.

When we run the query we get the below error.

> ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 2
>   ORA-04031: unable to allocate 32 bytes of shared memory ("shared pool","select i.obj#,i.ts#,i.file#,...","SQLA","tmp")

Note that the table is partitioned based on C3_Date column. But with the above logic we will still have few records retained in the partitions and hence cannot go with the option of dropping an entire partition.

Can anyone suggest how to approach this delete for it to be more efficient and stable?

Plan as below:

```
Plan hash value: 2112788339

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name               | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | DELETE STATEMENT             |                    |     1 |    59 |       |  9080K  (2)| 30:16:07 |       |       |
|   1 |  DELETE                      | TABLE1             |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS               |                    |     1 |    59 |       |  9080K  (2)| 30:16:07 |       |       |
|   3 |    VIEW                      | VW_NSO_1           |   496M|  5684M|       |  6785K  (1)| 22:37:12 |       |       |
|   4 |     SORT UNIQUE              |                    |     1 |    11G|       |            |          |       |       |
|*  5 |      VIEW                    |                    |   496M|    11G|       |  6785K  (1)| 22:37:12 |       |       |
|   6 |       WINDOW SORT            |                    |   496M|    20G|    26G|  6785K  (1)| 22:37:12 |       |       |
|*  7 |        INDEX SKIP SCAN       | XPKTABLE1          |   496M|    20G|       |  1206K  (1)| 04:01:18 |       |       |
|   8 |    TABLE ACCESS BY USER ROWID| TABLE1             |     1 |    47 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - filter("RANK"<>1)
   7 - access("C3_Date"<ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE@!,-15))
       filter("C3_Date"<ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE@!,-15))
```

Comment: Could you post an explain plan for this query ? Just do `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR DELETE from TABLE1  where .... .....`, then run `SELECT * FROM Table( DBMS_XPLAN.Display )`, and then copy the result (as a text), and paste it into the question.

Comment: 4031 is an unusual error that is likely not related to query optimization.  4031 implies significant memory problems.  Those problems were probably caused by other processes, and the query that failed is not really the cause of the problem.  If it's just a test database, and you think it's a fluke, I'd just restart it.

Answer (score 0):

This query generates a large amount of temp segments (26G) as shown in SQL plan and query estimated to run more than 30 hours. Therefore you receive ORA-04031 in runtime.

These are my kind recommendations.

I suggest you do not use analytical functions in sub-queries for large segments because they prevent optimizer from sub-queries unnesting and therefore generate runtime views.

The second recommendation is to append partition elimination predicate and explicitly provide date value by using literal or bind variable. Pre-compute it in PL/SQL block before executing query. Do not use non-deterministic function SYSDATE for the condition. Also it would be nice to reserve the reasonable condition for lower date bound (this is concern of design).

The third is to let Oracle by itself find rowid of rows that must by deleted by using another condition instead of explicitly providing rowid(s). It can reduce the number of logical I/Os in our case (use autotrace to verify).

And finally the query might be something like this (I've not verified it but only want to express the idea):

```
delete from TABLE1 t1_1
 where C3_Date < :upper_date_bound
   and C3_Date >= :lower_date_threshold
   and (C1_Varchar2, C2_Varchar2, C3_Date) not in 
       (select C1_Varchar2, C2_Varchar2, max(C3_Date)
          from table1 t1_2
         where C3_Date < :upper_date_bound
           and C3_Date >= :lower_date_bound
      group by C1_Varchar2, C2_Varchar2)
```

Because of the number of rows to be deleted is less than half of table you can consider the "IN" or "EXISTS" clause with another subquery instead of "NOT IN". For example, create local index on C3_Date column, perform statistic gathering and try this part in main query

```
...
exists (select null from table1 t1_2
         where t1_2.C1_Varchar2 = t1_1.C1_Varchar2
           and t1_2.C2_Varchar2 = t1_1.C2_Varchar2
           and t1_2.C3_Date = t1_1.C3_Date
           /* don't forget about partition selectivity hint */
           and t1_2.C3_Date < :upper_date_bound
           and t1_2.C3_Date >= :lower_date_bound         
         group by t1_2.C1_Varchar2, t1_2.C2_Varchar2
        having t1_1.C3_Date < max(t1_2.C3_Date))
```

--

Regards

Comment: I see queries run out of temporary tablespace all the time but I've never seen one of them generate ORA-4031.  I'm still not convinced this question is even about performance.

Answer (score -1):

Consider inserting in chunks (data for 1 day) as a much efficient and stable alternative.

Even just 12% months data in TABLE1  is huge (approx. 200 mn) !

The query in the current state can cause ORA-01555 (read consistency) errors as well. It will handle UNDO as well.

I have not tested this sample code but it will give you an idea how you can create chunks (1 for each day) manually.

The idea is to get max and min C3_Date before 20 months. Navigate from min date to max date.

Try adding a suitable on 'C3_Date' as a leading column to prevent 'INDEX SKIP SCAN'. That may help a bit too. Good luck!

```
var i_days number ;                             
SELECT (max(C3_Date) - min(C3_Date)) into :i_days  from TABLE1 where C3_Date < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -20);

-- CHANGE i_mig_start_date IN PROD, if required
var i_mig_start_date varchar2(30); 
exec :i_mig_start_date := ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -20)); 
--exec :i_mig_start_date := '03-OCT-2016 16:00:00';
declare 
    i number;
    v_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
    l_cmd_str VARCHAR2(4000);
    l_from_datetime date;
    l_to_datetime date;
begin
    -- Process chunk  (1 day)
    FOR i IN 1..:i_days LOOP
         l_from_datetime := to_date(:i_mig_start_date,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')-(i);
         l_to_datetime   := to_date(:i_mig_start_date,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')-(i-1);

        l_cmd_str := 'DELETE from /*+ PARALLEL(TABLE1  4)*/ TABLE1 
                    where ROWID IN (SELECT rid from (SELECT ROWID rid, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY C1_Varchar2,C2_Varchar2 ORDER BY C3_Date desc) as Rank 
                                                from TABLE1 where C3_Date > to_date(:l_from_datetime) and C3_Date <= to_date(:l_to_datetime))
                                    where Rank <> 1
                                    )';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Processing cycle i #'              || i || ' From: ' || l_from_datetime || ' To: ' || l_to_datetime ) ;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_cmd_str) ;
        execute immediate l_cmd_str using l_from_datetime, l_to_datetime;
        commit;
    END LOOP;    
end;
/
```

Comment: I would be glad I can get constructive feedback on 'why' a down vote ... Thanks!!